# Was there really a wide gap between the performance of the F-16 similar contestants in the Lightweight Fighter Contest?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter

Five manufacturers submitted proposals – Vought's V-1100, Lockheed's CL-1200   the Boeing Model 908 and the F-16 and F-17. The F-16 turned out to be an agile dogfighter with "superior acceleration, climb rates, endurance, and (except around Mach 0.7) turn rates"(Wikipedia). Given that the Boeing and Vought designs resembled the F-16, would it be fair to assume that their performance would have been quite similar? Answers would have to be based on the specifications as well as a guess as to agility in combat.

Comment: The YF-17 looked a lot (lot) like the F-18. The Boeing design *somewhat* resembled the F-16, but I can't see much similarity between the F-16 and the V-1100... Maybe you are thinking about the [Vought V-1600/1601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_Model_1600)? The V-1600 was supposed to be a Navalized version of the F-16, so its performance should be on-par with the F-16.

Comment: Suggest you read [The Pentagon Paradox](https://www.amazon.com/Pentagon-Paradox-Development-F-18-Hornet/dp/0788156411) as background to this question even though it is a direct criticism of the F-18 buy, not the F-16 buy.  The High Low Mix was another DoD fantasy in the world of procurement, the same mentality that has brought us the F-35.  Some things do not change.

Comment: Ron, the Vought V-1100 looked similar to the F-16, with a high wing, however other images I just found here http://www.afwing.com/intro/f16_talk/f16_viper/f16_viper-6.htm shows a longer wing. Also, the Boeing model 908 has a swept wing as far as I can see from the image. Thanks.

Comment: Kovin, thanks for the link. Where can I find more information on the war scenarios where the F-16 was planned to be used in? What about the F-35? Thanks.

Comment: GD and Northrup won the contracts to build the prototype F-16 and F-17 based on a proposal package.  Since it was nothing but paper, it's hard to say how the competing designs would have fared.  In a government procurement, proposals are evaluated against criteria (technical, managerial, cost) that are provided to the bidders in the request for proposal. A badly written proposal can kill a good design. Here's a recent article on the F-16/F-17 [competition](http://www.airforcemag.com/MagazineArchive/Documents/2017/February%202017/0217lightweigh.pdf).